# iterating hash collection

Tags: ruby, hash, mapping

```
{"Journal"=>[[4, -785.0], 
             [13, -21.9165000915527], 
             [14, -213.008995056152], 
             [15, -50.074499130249]]}
```

How can you to iterate this hash in Ruby, and how would you to separate out keys & values?

Comment: if you need to iterate through a hashmap, you are maybe using the wrong container

Comment: @Scoregraphic - not necessarily - this isn't all that uncommon. Example: serializing data.

Comment: Wait, do you have a hash with a single key/value pair whose value is an array of arrays?

Answer (score 21):

Ruby has a uniform iteration interface. All collections in Ruby have a method called `each`, which allows you to iterate over each element of the collection. Note, however, that explicit iteration is a code smell. You should mostly use higher-level iterators like `map`, `reduce`, `select`, `find`, `reject` and such.

In this particular case where the collection is a `Hash`, each element that is being yielded to your block, is a two-element array consisting of the key and the value:

```
print hsh.reduce('') {|s, el|
  s << "The key is #{el.first} and the value is #{el.last}.\n"
}
```

Thanks to Ruby's destructuring bind, you can simply bind the two elements of the array to two variables in your block and you won't have the need to constantly take the array apart:

```
print hsh.reduce('') {|s, (k, v)|
  s << "The key is #{k} and the value is #{v}.\n"
}
```

Answer (score 14):

```
myHash.each do |key, value|
  // key holds the key, value holds the value
end
```

In case want to transform the arrays inside your array to a map do this:

```
myNewHash = {}
myArrayOfArrays = myHash["Journal"]
myArrayOfArrays.each do | item |
  myNewHash[item[0]] = item[1]
end
```